# Django filtering data from primary key relational tables

Tags: django

I have a read-only MSSQL database which I successfully managed to read from using django.
This database's got tables which are all primary-keyed and models are:

```
class City(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Neighborhood(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    neighborhood = models.ForeignKey(Neighborhood)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I wish to filter `Person` by supplying `Neighborhood` and/or `City`.
Unfortunately I cannot alter tables or change db as it's read-only. How can it be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django you can query Person by their foreign key relationship.  I believe this is what you're looking for...

```
yourObject = Person.objects.filter(neighborhood__name="yourName")
```